# Changing an embedded UITextView width on rotation?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITextView embedded inside a grouped table view cell that I can't seem to update on rotation. It basically keeps the same width (assumed portrait) when it becomes landscape, causing about 40% of the view to be blank on the left side.

Is there a way to update this easily? I was looking at `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` but I wasn't sure if that was the right thing to update the view on rotation.

Specifically, I'm thinking the **width** value should be updated, since it's based on the width.

```
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                NSString *label = [self.pedal detail];
                CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * .95;
                CGSize stringSize = [label sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
                                      constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999)
                                          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                UITextView *textField = [[UITextView alloc] init];
                [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(50,0, width-10, stringSize.height+55)];
                [textField setEditable:NO];
                textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
                textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                cell.accessoryView = textField;
                textField.text = [self.pedal detail];
                [textField release];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`, which streches the object on its width on view size change.

Read more at the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask)

Comment: Wow, really that easy. For some reason I can't confirm this as the answer for another eight minutes, but I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have tried setting the sizing properties in IB right?  The way the object scales and what points are anchors should be able to be set there.

Comment: I'm doing it programatically, so that's not an option. In retrospect, I should've designed in IB.